# Getting the first anchor of first li inside the first ul only

Tags: html, css

I know how to get the first anchor of my li but the thing is, my code has 2 sub-menus of the same class and I want only the first ul to be affected.

```
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Main menu</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub menu</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Sub sub menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub sub menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub sub menu</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, please be sure of your code when you first post your question in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to use the `:first-child` you can use this:

***Updated code and demo after the question was updated.***

```
#navigation > ul > li > ul > li > a {color:red;}
```

This will only select the first `<li><a>` of the list, check the demo.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7Prmb/1/)**

Comment: Hey man, I like your demo and the fact that I don't need to use :first-child, please check the original post again, it is now edited since I forgot to put some HTML parts in it. Sorry!

Comment: Oke no problem, so now you want only the first `<ul>` to be affected in the css, not the `<li>` anymore? am i right?

Comment: No, everything is the same, I want first "ul.sub-menu li a" to be affected. Your code didn't work before, I think that is because there are some additional ul and li in the original code (that is why I edited the original post).

Answer (score 5):

I can't find an anchor in your code, but I'm assuming that each `<li>` would contain one? In that case this is how you would select it:

```
#navigation > ul > li:first-child a{color:#FFF}
```

As it stands, the `first-child` isn't really needed - this would only come into play if you were to add more `<li>`s directly after the one you are aiming at.

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/hqzUn/)

**After your edit**

You changed the code, so I guess I should update my answer. To target the 'main menu' anchor:

```
#navigation > ul > li > a{color:#F00}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/pHaQP/)

To target the first sub-menu anchor:

```
#navigation > ul > li > ul > li > a{color:#F00}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/pHaQP/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean an anchor inside every li, something like that:

```
#navigation .sub-menu:first-child li:first-child a {
    background-color: yellow;
}

<div id="navigation">
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li> <a href="#">1<a/>
        </li>
            <li> <a href="#">1.1<a/>
        </li>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">2<a/></li>
            <li><a href="#">3<a/></li>
            <li><a href="#">4<a/></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I intentionally added another li for the 1st ul - to make sure it works.

See JSFiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/rKynY/4/

[image]